# Clarification about some steps in the derivation of the Lie derivative (mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

First of all, this question may seem to be undefined, because I'm not sure how to connect this (to me) newly introduced concept with the abstract notion of the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative). I'm not even sure if I understood the process of obtaining the formula correctly, so please be gentle in the comments.

Suppose that $$ \dot {\stackrel{\to }{x}}(t)=\stackrel{\to }{\mathcal{F}}\left(\stackrel{\to }{x}\left(t\right)\right)$$ is a first order autonomous system with $n$ degrees of freedom, $\stackrel{\to }{x}(t)=(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$. Let's say we want to look at the time evolution of a volume in the phase space of that system (the diagram, of course, is purely schematic).

[image: Phase space diagram]

We consider the position of an object at the initial moment $t=0$ and another moment in time t. Those are given as $\stackrel{\to}{x}(0)$ and $\stackrel{\to}{x}(t)$ respectively. This enables us to consider volumes in the phase space at the initial and arbitrary moment ($\delta V(0)$ and $\delta V(t)$ respectively).

Now the fun starts. The formula which is given to calculate the time evolution is 
 $$\delta V(t)=\left|\frac{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(t\right)}{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(0\right)}\right|\delta V(0),\hspace{35pt} (1)$$
 where $\left|\frac{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(t\right)}{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(0\right)}\right|$ is the determinant of the Jacobi matrix: $$\frac{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(t\right)}{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(0\right)}=\left(\frac{\partial {x}_{i}\left(t\right)}{\partial {x}_{j}\left(0\right)}\right).$$

The rest of the steps are pretty straightforward: for $t\to 0$ we have the Taylor series $$\stackrel{\to }{x}(t)=\stackrel{\to }{x}(0)+\dot {\stackrel{\to }{x}}(0)t+O(t^2) $$ $$\Rightarrow \space \stackrel{\to }{x}(t)=\stackrel{\to }{x}(0)+\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}[\stackrel{\to}{x}(0)]t+O(t^2)$$ 
$$\Rightarrow \space \left|\frac{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(t\right)}{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(0\right)}\right|=det[I+\frac{d\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}}{d\stackrel{\to}{x}}|_{t=0}\cdot t+O(t^2)]=1+t\cdot \mathrm{Tr}(\frac{d\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}}{d\stackrel{\to}{x}}|_{t=0})+O'(t^2),$$
under the assumption that $\dot {\stackrel{\to}{x}}=\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}(\stackrel{\to}{x})$ and $\frac{d\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}}{d\stackrel{\to}{x}}$ are not divergent. $I$ is the unit matrix. By plugging 
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\frac{d\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}}{d\stackrel{\to}{x}}|_{t=0})=\nabla \cdot \mathcal{\stackrel{\to}{F}|_{t=0}}$$ into the Jacobian and finally into equation (1) we get
$$\underset{t\to 0}{lim}\frac{\delta V(t)-\delta V(0)}{t}=\delta V(0) \cdot (\nabla\cdot\mathcal{\stackrel{\to}{F}})$$ which yields the Lie derivative:
$$\mathcal{L_{F}}(\delta V)=\frac{1}{\delta V}\frac{d\delta V}{dt}=\nabla \cdot \mathcal{\stackrel{\to}{F}}|_{t=0}=\sum_i \frac{\partial \dot x_i}{\partial x_i},$$ which is in turn interpreted as a relative volume change of a part of the phase space.

---

I have a few questions:

1. How can we get that the volume time evolution is given by $\delta V(t)=\left|\frac{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(t\right)}{\partial \stackrel{\to }{x}\left(0\right)}\right|\delta V(0)$ ?
2. When we ask for the determinant of $I+\frac{d\stackrel{\to}{\mathcal{F}}}{d\stackrel{\to}{x}}|_{t=0}\cdot t+O(t^2)$, the unit matrix gives 1, the $O(t^2)$ gives more gibberish, but why is the second term the trace of matrix no. 2?
3. How did we get $\frac{1}{\delta V}\frac{d\delta V}{dt}=\nabla \cdot \mathcal{\stackrel{\to}{F}}|_{t=0}$?

Again, those questions are probably easily answered, but I don't seem to see the forest from the woods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a week of searching, I've found the answers to the questions myself (with a little help from associates):

1. The [general volume element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element) transformation is given by the formula with the Jacobian, nothing particularly interesting going on there.
2. The whole determinant is actually given by an identity valid in the limit of small time t: we choose to neglect all factors with $t^2$ or higher (i.e. we're neglecting $O(t^2)$, so the calculation goes as follows: $$det(I+tA)=
   \left|\begin{array} 1
     1+tA_{11} & tA_{12} & . & tA_{1n} \\ 
   tA_{21} & 1+tA_{22} & . & . \\ 
   . & . & . & . \\ 
   tA_{n1} & . & . & 1+tA_{nn}
   \end{array}\right| 
   =
   \left(1+tA_{11}\right)\left|\begin{array} 1
   1+tA_{22} & . & . & tA_{2n} \\ 
   tA_{32} & . & . & .\\ 
   . & . & . & . \\ 
   tA_{n2} & . & . & 1+tA_{nn}
   \end{array}\right|
   -
   tA_{12}\left|\begin{array}t
   tA_{21} & tA_{23} & . & . & tA_{2n} \\ 
   1+tA_{31} & . & . & . & . \\ 
   . & . & . & . & . \\ 
   tA_{n2} & . & . & . & 1+tA_{nn}
   \end{array}\right|+... \space\mathrm{(these\space terms\space vanish\space because\space the\space order\space of\space t^2\space and\space higher\space is\space neglected)}
   =
   \left(1+tA_{11}\right)\left(1+tA_{22}\right)\left|\begin{array}1
   1+tA_{33} & . & . & tA_{3n} \\ 
   tA_{43} & . & . & .\\ 
   . & . & . & . \\ 
   tA_{n3} & . & . & 1+tA_{nn}
   \end{array}\right| + O(t^2)=...=
   \prod _{i=1}^{n}\left(1+t{A}_{ii}\right)
   =1+t\cdot \mathrm{Tr}A+O(t^2)
   $$

3.For the third question I realized that I haven't copied the material from the blackboard in the right order, so I've edited the derivation in order to eliminate this question.